# Can you add spring dynamics to a joint (urdf)?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to simulate a spring within the joints of a robot leg. I've managed to use

```
    <gazebo reference="Joint">
        <implicitSpringDamper>true</implicitSpringDamper>
        <springStiffness>50</springStiffness>
        <springReference>0.8</springReference>
    </gazebo>
```

in the urdf to simulate a spring in that joint, but it only works when running the robot in gazebo. Is there a proper way to set up spring dynamics inside the joint in the urdf so that it works in rviz as well? I'm using melodic ros if that matters. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399179/can-you-add-spring-dynamics-to-a-joint-(urdf)?/) by [botboy](https://answers.ros.org/users/102369/botboy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a proper way to set up spring dynamics inside the joint in the urdf so that it works in rviz as well?

RViz is not a simulator, but a visualisation tool.

There is nothing in RViz which could do anything (different) with the information about a spring in a specific `joint`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn is absolutely correct that RViz is not a simulator and has nothing to do with the spring dynamics on your simulated robot. That being said, if all you want to do is visualize the joint in Rviz as the joints compress and extend in Gazebo, then you will need to make sure the joint states for all your non-fixed joints are being published.

The [gazebo_ros_pkgs `joint_state_publisher` plugin](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/231a7219b36b8a6cdd100b59f66a3df2955df787/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.h#L44-L52) is one way to do this.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2022-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3